# Restricting REST API results based on the user

Tags: rest, backbone.js, oauth-2.0

I am building a messaging application using BackboneJS which naturally persists using a REST interface.

The issue I'm having is that I don't know how to restrict what data a user can pull back from the API. For instance a call to /messages would, at the moment, return messages for ALL users. I would like that resource to only return messages belonging to the current user.

Searching online seems to indicate that oAuth2 is the best way to solve this issue but all the tutorials talk about been redirected to another place to confirm access and retrieve an access token.

Given that my users will have already logged into the message application and that the REST API is actually part of the same application I don't like the idea of asking the users to confirm that my own app can access my own API.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Is this is node project?

Comment: You really should manage this on your server side. The server should be able to manage the session, and see who should be able to see what.

Comment: @JonathanMiles No it's regular, old PHP running on Apache with Backbone on the client side

Comment: @YuruiRayZhang Yes the data should be limited on the server side but since REST is stateless there's no way of the server knowing WHO the client is without me implementing something like oAuth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oAuth2 is probably your best bet -- you definitely don't want to roll your own security. However, the flavor of oAuth2 you are thinking of is probably not what you want.

oAuth2 has four different flavors, known as authorization grant types:

1. Authorization code: This is the type you are thinking about. It is often called three-legged oAuth, because there are three actors in the token granting process (app, resource owner, and user). The app asks the user whether it is ok for the resource owner to give specific type(s) of access to the resource. It is a rather complex process that allows the validation of user credentials without allowing the app access to them. This is not necessary in your case, since you are both the app and resource owner.
2. Client credentials: This is a method for authorizing a client application with the server. It does not use user credentials at all. If you **completely** trust your client application (all client applications) to correctly protect user data and not expose other user's data to the user using the app, or you are providing only non-user data via the API (for example, map data or catalog data), you might be able to use this fairly simple type of oAuth2. However, if you want to be vigilant in protecting user data (and not allow apps to get to the data without the user providing credentials), you might not use this one.
3. Resource owner password credentials: The username and password of the user is passed via https to your backend server, which authenticates and authorizes access by providing an access token. The access token can then be passed with each call, and it remains valid for accessing the backend until a configurable time period has elapsed. This means that someone intercepting the token could only use it successfully for a limited amount of time (some number of minutes, generally). The interceptor would not know the username and password of the user. In addition, you can supply the app with a refresh token, which can be used to get a new access token once it has expired (until the refresh token expires -- usually with a significantly longer expiration date). Since the credentials are not passed across the wire often (and must only be passed encrypted), this is often the best solution for protecting user credentials and not requiring the user to pass them in often (good user experience). Implementation is much simpler than for the authorization code grant type.
4. Implicit: This is the least secure method -- no credentials are validated server side at all. This is usually used for client side scripting languages where credentials cannot be stored safely. If you are worried about security at all, avoid this type if possible.

So, check out [OAuth 2.0](http://oauth.net/2/), and look for the resource owner password credentials grant type.

Comment: Ok I think I understand the difference then. What I need to do is request an access token from the API directly using the clients username and password. The API responds with an access token with a short lifespan and a refresh token with a longer life span. The access token is used for requests to identify the user and the refresh token is used to regenerate an access token when one expires?
You say don't roll your own? Is it a bad thing to write my own classes even if I follow the oAuth2 protocol?

Comment: Sounds like you've got it figured out. When I say don't roll your own, I mean don't design your own authentication protocol. Implementing oAuth2 yourself is fine. Good luck!